# Check if LI has A HREF link

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to add a class to the parent `<li>` if the text within the `<li>` includes a `<a href>` link.

So, the code below if I was to add the class "LinkerLi" to the parent `<li>` that had the link

```
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Another</li>
<li><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
</ul>
```

Would then become

```
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Another</li>
<li class"LinkerLi"><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
</ul>
```

Sure its a simple thing to sort, but I cant seem to get the logic working... Anyone got a solution? I was looking to use `contains` with `children` in jQuery but cant seem to get it to work...

Comment: Positive there's a duplicate (which is where I got the technique) - so: work backwards:  find the element then get its parent:  `$("li>a[href]").closest("li").addClass("linker")`

Comment: Yeh - just worked out a solution thinking about it another way > `$('li a').each(function() {

$(this).parent('li').addClass('LinkerLi');

});`

Comment: `$("li:has(a[href])")`.addClass(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get all anchors inside the list. Then iterate each one in order to add the `LinkerLi` class.

Here's the code:

`$('li a').each(function() {  $(this).parent('li').addClass('LinkerLi');  });`